# Building an NPM package that serves both React and React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

We are building an NPM package called Chat for a company project. It is based on a [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) reducer and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

For both **web** and **RN** the use is:

```
<Chat
    userName={user.userName}
    password={user.password}
    avatarUrl={user.avatarUrl}
    defaultAvatar={defaultAvatar}
    defaultGroupAvatar={defaultGroupAvatar}
    name={user.name}
/>
```

However there are differences between **web** and **mobile**:

- **Dependencies:** RN requires react-native and other RN packages, while web requires react-textarea-autosize and other web packages. Needless to say, installing React Native's packages for web is quite an overhead.
- **Compilation:** RN can work with ES6 but web requires babel to transpile to JS.

We thought of two different ways to go about it:

1. Creating a base package with the common code: reducers and utils, and then create two additional packages for web and mobile components.
2. Placing the dependencies from package.json in peerDependencies.

Both ways have their downsides. The first one creates a clutter of packages and the second one means the package.json is not descriptive. Any better way to go with it? What is the proper way to build cross-platform React NPM packages?

Comment: Just like RN separates ios and android, add a third entry point for web and add all the needed build scripts for web.

Comment: I'll take a look. with different package.json files?

Comment: It'd be the same package. You can have packages for each platform but like you said you'll have to take out the common code and create packages for reuse in the other platform packages. I wouldn't do this unless you really want to isolate source control for each platform. Extra dependencies that appear on the package just sit unused in your working dir but shouldn't affect production performance.

Comment: @Guy, I also need to build firebase chat package for ReactJS and React-Native. Would you please share your solution for this? Thanks in advance.